# Is there a way to set up random access to encrypted data in Android?

Tags: java, android, encryption, random-access

I'm currently trying to provide a transparent encryption/decryption layer to files stored on an Android device. I need random access to each of these files (necessary for search algorithm). The layer needs to provide either a RandomAccessFile or a FileChannel to the rest of the program.

My (very) basic understanding of crypto suggests that certain cipher modes like ECB, CTR, XEX, and XTR could facilitate random access, but I'd rather use somebody else's tool before I reinvent the wheel. Much better to leave crypto to the experts.

An ideal solution would be an encrypted disk image that I could access using a Java library, but I haven't found anything that I could use for Android.

Is there a way for me to provide random access to encrypted files? This feels like something that a lot of people would want in their apps!

Answer (score 0):

Random read access is easy: use CTR, but make sure you have correct key and nonce usage. Random write access *could* be just as easy, although with CTR you are leaking information in time if you change any block. So if an attacker simply gets a single view of one file then you would be OK, otherwise you directly leak information about the plain text.

You've got a specific usage scenario. If there are any libs that do this for you I haven't seen them yet. Furthermore, the key management is usually application specific too. I am afraid you will have to deal with threat scenarios.

ECB should not be used for related information such as strings or files. XEX (or XTS for that matter) is normally not available in Java crypto libraries (such as the Oracle JCE or Bouncy).